# Changing the order fixed my error. Why?

Tags: c, io

It took me awhile to figure out this error and was wondering why the second block of code doesn't work.

Working:

```
FILE *readFile;
FILE *saveFile;

char readFileName;
char saveFileName;

printf("read file name:\n");
scanf("%s", &readFileName);
readFile = fopen(&readFileName, "r");

printf("save file name:\n");
scanf("%s", &saveFileName);
saveFile = fopen(&saveFileName, "w");
```

Didn't work:

```
FILE *readFile;
FILE *saveFile;

char readFileName;
char saveFileName;

printf("read file name:\n");
scanf("%s", &readFileName);

printf("save file name:\n");
scanf("%s", &saveFileName);

readFile = fopen(&readFileName, "r");
saveFile = fopen(&saveFileName, "w");
```

Comment: Good luck not having undefined behaviour when trying to squeeze an elephant into a backpack of space.

Comment: `readFileName` and `saveFileName` are `char`, so they can hold only a single character. Use `char` arrays or pointers instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a reference to a single `char` allocated on a stack. That pointer is invalid to be used a reference to an array of character.

Try replacing your strings with a real array of character used as a buffer:

```
char readFileName[128];
scanf("%127s", readFileName);
```

otherwise what will happen is that `scanf`, that doens't check anything, will overwrite data on the stack with characters fetched from `stdio`, causing a [stack buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow), and this means undefined behavior.

You can specify how many characters to fetch at most in the format specifier, but remember to subtract one since a [`null` terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) is automatically appended by `scanf` itself.

Comment: *otherwise what will happen is that `scanf` ... will overwrite data on the stack* That problem exists here, too

Comment: Yes, but a filename is not likely to be longer than 128 bytes. Problem is that scanf is just not safe enough :) In anycase I guess that adding a width specifier should fix the issue.

Comment: I think `scanf("%127s", readFileName)` would be safe (if I got the syntax correct).

Comment: Yes, it should. Never happened to use it though.

Answer (score 2):

It is by pure luck (*undefined behavior*) that one version of your program worked.

```
char readFileName;
...
scanf("%s", &readFileName);
readFile = fopen(&readFileName, "r");
```

You are writing an entire file name to a memory space of only one byte! Presumably you meant something like:

```
char readFileName[1024];
...
scanf("%s", readFileName);
readFile = fopen(readFileName, "r");
```

The "working" version of your program merely overwrote bytes that you don't immediately need to open the "save" file. That's why it appears to function correctly, even though it's wrong.

Be sure to allocate enough space before using `scanf()`.